# Limit of functions with alternating sign

Tags: limits

I can't seem to figure out how to calculate the limits of 
Functions with alternating signs.

e.g.,

$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}(-1)^{n+1} \frac{n}{n+n^{1/3}}
$$
Is there any specific method by which we can calculate these limits?

Answer (score 0):

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\frac{n}{n+n^{1/3}}\right)=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\frac{1}{1+n^{-2/3}}\right)=1$$
Assuming that $n$ is an integer the value of $(-1)^{n+1}$ flucatuates between $-1$ and $1$ as $n$ increases so in the limit the entire expression fluctuates between $-1$ and $1$. As the value of the limit fluctuates, the limit does  not exist.

Comment: More generally, from basically the same argument, an alternating sequence converges to $0$ or not at all.

Comment: @Arthur so is it always appropriate to just take the $(-1)^{n}$ out of the expression and see if the sum converges to $0$?

Comment: @Matthieu: sum ? Which sum ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust my apologies limit.

Comment: @Mattheiu Yes, it is.